# A question in fixed point interation and convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Can I get help in this question, I just want to understand it. 
$$
x_{n+1}=-\sin(x_n)^3-\sin(x_n)^4 , ~~x_0=-0.6
$$

- To find the convergence's order.
- Is the series a special case of fixed point iteration? (if yes find an equation that enables to find the series's root).
- Find an interval on the real line in which the series converges foe every starting point in this interval and prove this formally. What is the value that the series converges to?

I know the definitions...but couldn't manage to connect them to this series..because of sin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that $|\sin x|\le \min(1,|x|)$ so that
$$
|x_{n+1}|\le 2|x_n|^3.
$$
All the other answers easily follow from this.

---

Note that $|x_k|\le 2$, $k>0$, so that the following plot suggests that there are no other fixed points than the obvious one.

[image: add plot of root equation]

Comment: then I didn't understand how to use it in my exercise, cuz this as an inequality..

Comment: This inequality tells you immediately that the order of convergence is at least 3. A slight transformation to $(\sqrt2|x_{n+1}|)\le(\sqrt2 |x_n|)^3$ tells you that convergence is guaranteed for $|x_0|<1/\sqrt2$, which your initial value satisfies. // I do not rightly understand the second point, it is either trivial or deep. Anyway, if the sequence converges then you can use the continuity of the sine to get an equation for the limit point. There are alternative ways to solve that equation, like Newton, but they all again amount to fixed-point iterations.